# Inductive predicate in ACSL stating a linked list is a sublist of another

Tags: linked-list, sublist, frama-c, induction

I need to code, in ACSL, an inductive predicate stating that a linked list is a sublist of another.

The signature of the predicate should be something like this:

```
inductive subLinkedList{L1,L2} (LinkedList l) {
...
}
```

So basically I want a predicate stating that linkedlist l, on the state L1, is sublist of the same linkedlist l, but in this case in state L2.

Comment: the signature you're giving suggest that you want to consider the same list `l` at two different program points `L1` and `L2`. Is this really the case? In addition, what is your definition of a sublist exactly? should it be a prefix, a suffix, something in the middle of the longer list? Last, the definition of the `LinkedList` type would be useful.

Comment: Yes, it is the case. My definition of sublist can be understood with the following example:  4-> 5 is sublist of 2 -> 4 -> 5.